# Why my implicit function parameter does not work?

Tags: scala

Here is my code snippet:

```
implicit def trick(s: String): String = s.toUpperCase    
def fun(s: String)(implicit f: String => String): String = f(s)        
println(s"String is ${fun("abc")}")
```

When I run it, it prints "abc" instead of "ABC". What am I doing wrong here?

*PS*

However, if I run the next code

```
implicit val n: Int = 100
def add(n1: Int)(implicit n2: Int) = n1 + n2
add(7)
```

all implicit magic works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally this would work. The compiler would implicitly convert the implicit method to a function through eta-expansion. Say, if I wanted to require an implicit `Int => List[Int]` for some reason.

```
implicit def trick(i: Int): List[Int] = List.fill(5)(i)

def fun(i: Int)(implicit f: Int => List[Int]): List[Int] = f(i)

scala> fun(4)
res5: List[Int] = List(4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

But your problem is that there is *another* implicit `String => String` already in scope that comes from `Predef`. Namely `=:=[String, String]`, which extends `String => String`. Because this already exists in scope *as a function*, the compiler sees no need to look for anything else. *And*, if you convert your implicit method to an implicit function, you will get an ambiguous implicits error:

```
implicit val trick: String => String = _.toUpperCase

scala> fun("abc")
<console>:19: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method $conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> <:<[A,A]
 and value trick of type => String => String
 match expected type String => String
       fun("abc")
```

Really though, having an implicit `String => String` is probably not a good idea. Use a type class that wraps a function, instead.

```
case class Trick[A](f: A => A)

implicit val trick = Trick[String](_.toUpperCase)

def fun(s: String)(implicit t: Trick[String]): String = t.f(s)        

scala> println(s"String is ${fun("abc")}")
String is ABC
```